# Parse result from database LINQ

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I have the following LINQ query:

```
var query = (from c in _context.MapTextToLanguage
             where c.LanguageId == defaultLanguage
             where (c.Identifier == "home" || c.Identifier == "CV" || 
             c.Identifier == "contact" || c.Identifier == "manage" || 
             c.Identifier == "register" || c.Identifier == "login" || 
             c.Identifier == "logout" || c.Identifier == "about")
             select c.Text);
```

This returns what I am looking for, but the order of this list is given by in which order it finds the object in the database.

I would like if the result from query could be parsed into a model or that query[0] always is = home.

I could ask for the values separately, but this seems inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var output = query.OrderByDescending(x => x == "home");
```

to make output[0] return the text of the home identifier, alternatively:

```
//adjust your query to select c rather than c.Text
var output = query.ToDictionary(x => x.Identifier);
```

so that you can do output["home"].Text, output["CV"].Text etc.

Comment: Yes, that works. Which one do you think is faster? Thanks!

Comment: I would use .ToDictionary as the code is clearer, but I imagine the order by descending is marginally faster, if speed is really important I would always suggest running your own tests

Answer (score 1):

> Requirement: I would like if the result from query could be parsed into a model or that query[0] always is = home.

Like others said, you could use `OrderBy` or `ToDictionary` to put the "home" items first. However, this will enumerate your sequence more than once. Especially the OrderBy will compare items several times before it finds out that they are equal in Order.

But why compare all those items if you are only interested in putting one item with "Home" first?

Consider creating an extension function for your class that will Do what you want by enumerating exactly once. See [Extension Methods Demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
static IEnumerable<string>PutWordFirst(this IEnumerable<string> source, string word)
{
     List<string> nonWords = new List<string>();
     foreach(var text in source)
     {
         if (text == word)
         {
            yield return word;
         }
         else
         {
            nonWords.Add(text);
         }
    }

    foreach (var nonWord in nonWords) yield return nonWord;
 }
```

Usage:

```
var query = query = context.MapTextToLanguages
    .Where(language => ...)
    .Select(language => ...)
    .PutWordFirst("home");
```

If you want this generic: a function that puts the items with a certain property first:

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereItemFirst<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
       Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
       TKey keyValue,
       IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer)
{
    // TODO: exception if source, keySelector, keyValue null

    // if keyComparer null, use default comparer to compare TKeys
    if (keyComparer == null) keyComparer = EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;

    List<TSource> nonKeyItems = new List<TSource>();
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        if (comparer.Equals(keySelector(item), keyValue))
        {
            // return the item with a value equal to keyValue
            yield return item;
        }
        else
        {
            nonKeyItems.Add(item);
        }
    }

    // return the nonKey items:
    foreach (var nonKeyItem in nonKeyItems) yield return nonKeyItem;
 }
```

And a version without comparer:

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereItemFirst<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
       Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, TKey keyValue)
{
    // call the function above with null comparer, uses the default comparer
    return source.WhereItemFirst(keySelector, keyValue, null);
}
```

Usage: put the persons that live at my address first:

```
var myAddress = GetMyAddress();
var persons = GetPersons();
var myFamilyFirst = persons.WhereItemFirst(person => person.Address, myAddress);
```

Parameter `keySelector` extracts from every person his `Address`. The extracted `Address` is compared with `myAddress`. If it matches it is returned first.

Comment: My bad, it was not well formulated. What I wanted was the entire sequence to be equal each time. Thanks for the extensive answer though!